# Validate European VAT - VIES and Polish VAT verification

Tags: javascript, python, validation

I'm looking for some help with clear my mess in code. If anyone of u can help me in python,JS,php i will be glad, because i have written some scripts and its not working now and idk why. I can send code in private conversation.

Comment: Wrong forum. You need a freelancer.

Comment: Ok thank you , can u give some advice where i can find freelancer?

Comment: Try googling "where to find freelance programmers" you'll get some results. Be careful of fraud, use clear job description and see if the programmer has done jobs on that website and was positively rated.